# Zip the Folder in c# regardless of any number of subfolders inside it

Tags: asp.net, zip

I want to compress an entire directory which can have any number of subdirectories into a single ZIP file.I'm using the Ionic.Zip dll for that,but don't know how to proceed.

private void ZipFiles(string zipPath, string sourceDirectory, string strfilename)
        {

```
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(sourceDirectory,zipPath);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) like that:

```
SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.CompressDirectory(...);
```